# How to redirect non www to www on subdomain

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect non www to www in my sub domain.
my domain is using wordpress and my subdomain is using native site.

my domain, for example, https://www.example.com and subdomain is https://files.example.com, I want to add www in my subdomain, so my sub domain should be like this https://www.files.example.com.

btw I'm using cloudflare.

my domain(https://www.example.com) .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options -Indexes
```

here my subdomain(https://files.example.com) .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
#Main Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I try this too but still not working

```
RewriteEngine On
#Main Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just to be clear. If you type `https://www.files.example.com.` in a web browser it loads? CNAMES are all set?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Why? What good does adding `www` do?